# How to find and remove last link tags in a string with php?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a string like this but number of links can be different for each situation:

```
<a>link 1</a> >> <a>link 2</a> >> <a>link 3</a> >> <a>link 4</a>
```

I want to remove last link in that string and convert like this:

```
<a>link 1</a> >> <a>link 2</a> >> <a>link 3</a> >> link 4
```

Is there a simple function for that ? I know i can use several functions like preg_match, preg_match_all, explode etc... With these functions, removing first link tags pretty easy though removing last one is a little bit confusing.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is there any way you control this output? Parsing HTML is a relatively heavy solution, so if you can fix it at the source rather then later that would be preferable.

Comment: With regex you can just use `.*<a` to find the last one. If DOM can parse over those raw `>>` then you might get away with `htmlqp($h)->remove("a:last-child")` in e.g. [tag:querypath]

Comment: @mario Can you give me an example with regexp ? a piece of code may be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of regexp...

```
$str = '<p> 
<a>link 1</a> >> <a>link 2</a> >> <a>link 3</a> >> <a>link 4</a>    
</p>';
echo preg_replace('#^(.*)<a[^>]*?>(.*?)</a>(.*?)#im', '$1$2$3', $str);
```

Comment: works perfect. thanks a ton. can you give me a link which i can learn php regexp functions ?

Comment: @motto         Unfortunately I can not give any good advice here - I know many programming languages, some of them operate with regexps, so I do not remember what I was reading to understand them. I think it was related to Perl at first and it will be useful to you too, because PCRE (which is used by PREG - Perl REGular expression) = Perl Compartible Regular Expression. Open any book about Perl's regexps and than read http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php

Comment: thanks for the insightful information yet i didn't understand why the people liked and upvoted more a complicated answer instead of yours. to me, it will better to have simple solutions.

Comment: @motto It may be simpler, but it's not exactly robust. What about `<a href="" title="Did you know that 6 > 1?">link</a>`.

Comment: @alex LOL at a glance, i thought that function will fail with your example too but it works perfectly even with your example. any other thoughts ?

Comment: @motto That is because the regex has limited state and can not differentiate on its own what is an attribute and such.

Answer (score 3):

Use a DOM parser such as [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

```
$html = '<p> 
<a>link 1</a> >> <a>link 2</a> >> <a>link 3</a> >> <a>link 4</a>    
</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$lastA = $a->item($a->length - 1);

$dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($lastA->nodeValue));

$lastA->parentNode->removeChild($lastA);

$newHtml = '';

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
    $newHtml .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

echo $newHtml;
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fS1Lsp).

This code outputs...

```
<p> 
<a>link 1</a> &gt;&gt; <a>link 2</a> &gt;&gt; <a>link 3</a> &gt;&gt;     
link 4</p>
```

Of course, you **shouldn't** be using `>` literally in HTML (it should be encoded as `&gt;`). But if you must, use `html_entity_decode()` on the final HTML.

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kPoCYc).

Comment: thanks for your answer but i think i'm missing something here. is there a disadvantage, which i didn't noticed, of using a simple regexp function ? any particular reason to using dom parser ?